# scrapy-splash active content selector works in shell but not with spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I just started using scrapy-splash to retrieve the number of bookings from opentable.com. The following works fine in the shell:

```
$ scrapy shell 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://www.opentable.com/new-york-restaurant-listings&timeout=10&wait=0.5'    
...

In [1]: response.css('div.booking::text').extract()
Out[1]: 
['Booked 59 times today',
 'Booked 20 times today',
 'Booked 17 times today',
 'Booked 29 times today',
 'Booked 29 times today',
  ... 
]
```

However, this simple spider returns an empty list:

```
class TableSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'opentable'
    start_urls = ['https://www.opentable.com/new-york-restaurant-listings']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url,
                                callback=self.parse,
                                endpoint='render.html',
                                args={'wait': 1.5},
                                )

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {'bookings': response.css('div.booking::text').extract()}
```

when invoked with:

```
$ scrapy crawl opentable
...
DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.opentable.com/new-york-restaurant-listings>
{'bookings': []}
```

I've already unsuccessfully tried

```
docker run -it -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash --disable-private-mode
```

and increased wait times.

Comment: Print the response content and see what you get when you run in scrapy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is in `middlewares`, first of all you need to add some settings

```
# settings.py

# uncomment `DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES` and add this settings to it
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

# url of splash server
SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'

# and some splash variables
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

And now run docker

```
sudo docker run -it -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash --disable-private-mode
```

If i do all these steps a get back:

```
scrapy crawl opentable

...

2018-06-23 11:23:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.opentable.com/new-york-restaurant-listings via http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
2018-06-23 11:23:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.opentable.com/new-york-restaurant-listings>
{'bookings': [
    'Booked 44 times today',
    'Booked 24 times today',
    'and many others Booked values'
]}
```

Comment: You're right, I had actually just overlooked a second set of DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES in my settings that had overwritten those for `scrapy-splash`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because this content of the web is using JS.

You can adopt serveral solutions:

1) Use selenium.

2) If you see the API of the page, if you call this url `<GET https://www.opentable.com/injector/stats/v1/restaurants/<restaurant_id>/reservations>` you will have the number of current reservaitions of this specific restaurant (restaurant_id).